# Setting HTML drop down list option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to set value from php the option selected in a drop down list in html.
can anyone tell me how to give the "selected" attribute as the answer is generated dynamically

```
<select form="onsite_assessment" class="form-control" id="onsite_assessment">
        <option value="no">NO</option>
        <option value="yes">YES</option>
    </select>
```

In the above code if the user has selected No in the previous session. i want to display that option by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is just some general code which can be shaped for your needs. As I can't see all your code I cannot give a FULL answer. Basically you need to store the users' choice and retrieve this in a variable whenever needed, either string or Boolean (true/false). In the example I will show this using a string.

```
<?php
  $user_choice = 'yes';
?>

<select form="onsite_assessment" class="form-control" id="onside_assessment">
  <option value="no" <?php if($user_choice == 'no'){echo 'selected'; }>NO</option>
  <option value="yes" <?php if($user_choice == 'yes'){echo 'selected'; }>YES</option>
</select>
```